# Base path empty when running husky with windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, git-bash

Issue:

When running husky on my current environment an error occurs on the `pre-commit` hook as `dirname` returns an empty string on the following line of code of the block below:

```
#!/bin/sh
# husky

# Created by Husky v4.3.8 (https://github.com/typicode/husky#readme)
#   At: 26/10/2021 15:15:28
#   From: undefined (https://github.com/typicode/husky#readme)

. "$(dirname "$0")/husky.sh"
```

Using:

- Node: v14.15.1
- Husky: 4.3.8
- Git: version 2.31.1.windows.1
- OS: Windows 10

Both, Husky & Git, are installed at `C:` directory, under programs and files folder.

P.S: I have tried other versions of husky, but the problem remains, as it seems to be related to windows... I am not very good with windows system configs so if anyone could please help me to solve this issue I would be very pleased.

Comment: `$0` is a bash thing, not a Git thing; I updated your tags, but I'm not sure why bash on Windows would be missing a dirname portion and/or fool the `dirname` command, so I'll leave that part to others.